# The printf function in C is not working as intended

Tags: c, printf

Can someone help me with this issue? For some reason, no matter what I try, doing printf isn't printing in my code. I've been trying to use the flush method, but that seems to just cause other issues. Is there anything else I can do?

```
int main(void) {
char **line;
size_t bufsize=MAXBUF;
printf("Type your name: ");
getline(&line,&bufsize,stdin);


}
```

Comment: How about `printf("Type your name: \n");`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh It's a prompt, "\n" isn't needed.

Comment: In that case `fputs ("type your name: ", stdout);`

Comment: I'm voting this question up because i think it's a good question actually. Because of the interaction of printf and the flushing of stdout, it's very easy to lose the program output when there's a crash or memory fault (or even a hard lockup).

Comment: **Did you carefully read the documentation of [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)?** Its source code is in [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), and you are allowed to study and improve that source code

Comment: Read also the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and enable all warnings and debug info, so use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then use your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). BTW `line` is not initialized and contains garbage.

Comment: If you tell us about "other issues" please post them.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass in an empty pointer, this pointer isn't pointing to any meaningful address at the start of the program. So the problem with this is that even if you were successful, it would overwrite some random address in memory with the input, and this is almost certainly what you don't want as it will cause a segmentation fault or a crash.

However that's not the reason why it's not compiling. It's not compiling because you are trying to pass in char *** to a function that expects char **.

So what I would do is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *line=NULL;
  size_t bufsize=0;
  printf("Type your name: ");
  if(getline(&line,&bufsize,stdin)==-1){
    puts("Error: User cancelled input.");
  }
  else{
    printf("Entered: %s",line);
  }
  free(line);
  return 0;
}
```

So what this code does is that it creates a pointer to an array of characters but it sets the pointer to point to NULL so that the program can see it's not pointing anywhere, and then its address (&line) is given to the getline function, this turns the char * type into a char ** which is required by the getline function. Whenever you put a & in front of something in C, it adds an extra * to the type.

You probably know this already, but if a function states that it returns something, you should always return something, even if it's nonsense otherwise depending on the type that should be returned, that can sometimes cause a crash.

There was nothing wrong with your use of printf, that was fine. printf doesn't necessarily fflush to stdout, often the \n character will trigger a flush, but it's implementation specific, so if your program crashes before an fflush is written to stdout, then you may never see the last printf. You can try an fflush(stdout); *before* the getline function, but after the getline function may not work because it may crash before then.

In your case what's happening is that before the printf writes to the screen the getline takes in the address of the pointer (or pointer to a pointer), dereferences it to a pointer, isn't able to, so before you have a chance to enter in any keystrokes it crashes, losing the stdout pipe, so you end up never seeing your prompt.

When i run the altered code, above, i get:

```
XXXX@dell:~$ gcc Deleteme.c 
XXXX@dell:~$ ./a.out 
Type your name: test1
Entered: test1
XXXX@dell:~$
```

And it runs correctly under Linux. The key lesson in all this is that, terminals are slow to update on the screen, so some time in the past, the decision was made to separate out the functionality of printf.

There are two components to printf:

1. The part that writes the text to stdout.
2. The part that updates the terminal with stdout (the flush).

This question is interesting because 1) succeeded, but the system crashed before 2) was completed.

Comment: Very good effort. The only thing needed for an UV is the ***validation*** of the user-input. For example `if (getline(&ptr,&bufsize,stdin) == -1) { puts ("(user canceled input)"); return 0 }` as it is perfectly valid for the user to generate a manual `EOF` or they may redirect an empty-file as input. (and you may even want to save the return so you know the number of characters read without having to call `strlen()` later. The return is a bit odd with type `ssize_t`, but that is the accommodation ... (hack) to handle the signed return from `getline()`.

Comment: That's a really good point actually. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in answering any of the questions related to user-input, it is always worth impressing on the OP that until you know whether the input succeeded or failed -- you don't really know whether you have valid data. Proceeding to use the pointer or variable after an input failure generally results in UB. So unvalidated input is like playing Russian Roulette, or rolling dice with UB -- the cylinder will come up full or you will roll snake-eyes sooner or later `:)`

Comment: Yes, true that, especially where pointers are concerned!

Comment: Ahh i see, so because it's on the stack rather than the heap, realloc will fail. Haha, thanks i didn't see that. I'll adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, it must be that the getline triggers an fflush, presumably because it has to echo keystrokes. So an fflush shouldn't normally be needed before getline. Unless of course, you're expecting problems like OP had ;)

Comment: Given the [link](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), it has "This buffer
should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed." so `free(line);` is best coded even when `getline()` returns -1.

Comment: "it must be that the getline triggers an fflush": I doubt `getline()` on `stdin` or any input stream triggers a flush on `stdout`.

Comment: Appreciate the comments, i realise i don't use getline very much. I learnt a lot - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `getline` says the first parameter must be a `char **`, but you pass it the address of `line`. Since line is a `char **`, `&line` is a `char ***`, which is the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

[`getline()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) allocates and re-allocates memory.  The address of the length and the buffer need to reflect that.

```
int main(void) {
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t bufsize = 0;
  printf("Type your name: ");
  fflush(stdout); // Flush output before reading.
  ssize_t len = getline(&line, &bufsize, stdin);
  if (len < 0) Handle_error_with_code();
  ...
  free(line);  // When done, free memory
}
```

There is no need to allocate any memory before calling `getline()`.

`getline()` expects `line, bufsize` to reflect allocated data via `malloc()` and friends.  It is easy enough to start with `NULL, 0` here.

Answer (score 0):

First you are passing the address of `line` to the `getline()`, the documentation says that the first argument is the address of the first **character** position where the input string will be stored. It’s not the base address of the buffer, but of the first character in the buffer.
This pointer type (a pointer-pointer or the ** thing) causes massive confusion.

second your `line` pointer does not point to anything this should fix it:

```cpp
char *line = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
```

now `line` is pointing to valid memory address which we requested via `malloc()` function.